# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' error using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to map an object to a database using SQLAlchemy but have run into a snag.

```
Edit: Basically changed a whole bunch of stuff.
```

Version info if handy: [OS: Mac OSX 10.5.8 | Python: 2.6.4 | SQLAlchemy: 0.5.8]

The class I'm going to map:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" %(self.id, self.name)
```

Background:

Now, I've got a function that reads in the necessary information from a text database into these objects. The function more or less works and I can easily access the information from the objects.

Before the SQLAlchemy code runs, the function will read in the necessary info and store it into the Class. There is a dictionary called `students` which stores this as such:

```
students = {}
students[id] = Student(<all the info from the various "reader" functions>)
```

Afterwards, there is an "allocation" algorithm that will allocate projects to student. It does that well enough. The `allocated_project` remains as `None` if a student is unsuccessful in getting a project.

SQLAlchemy bit:

So after all this happens, I'd like to map my object to a database table.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
metadata = MetaData()
students_table = Table('studs', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String)
)
metadata.create_all(engine)
mapper(Student, students_table)
```

Now after that, I was curious to see if I could print out all the students from my students dictionary.

```
for student in students.itervalues():
    print student
```

What do I get but an error. This error only takes place if try to print as I am, *after* calling the `mapper`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/FYP_Tests/FYP_Tests.py", line 140, in <module>
    print student
  File "~/FYP_Tests/Parties.py", line 30, in __str__
    return "%s %s" %(self.id, self.name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 158, in __get__
  return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), instance_dict(instance))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I'm at a loss as to how to resolve this issue, if it is an issue. If more information is required, please ask and I will provide it.

```
Questions:
```

1. Does the SQLAlchemy `mapper` change anything about the original Class/dictionary?
2. Does this have anything specific to way the `get` works with dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `Student` instances before mapping class which modifies class to SQLAlchemy needs. So your instance is not properly initialized. Just put the lines creating `Student` instances *after* calling `mapper(Student, students_table)` and everything will work as expected.

Comment: I think you've nailed it. When I try this sort of fancy `for students in students.itervalues: session.add(student)` I get an error that says something about creating an instance before mapping.  

So, basically, this bit of database code should sit before I start reading in the information from the text files?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a name shadowing conflict where `Column('id'...)` hides Student.id. Changing `Student.__init__.id` to `Student._init__.sid` would be a quick test to confirm or refute this conjecture.

There is mention of this connection in the third code block of the [SQLAlchemy tutorial on mappings](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/ormtutorial.html#define-a-python-class-to-be-mapped).

For example, replacing your first code snippet with this fragement:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.sid = id
        self.name = name
        # and so on
```

Obviously other references to `Student.id` would have to change as well.

Comment: @msw: Will try and let you know.

Comment: I added the "quick test" sentence to (hopefully) clarify

Comment: @msw: Just double-checking, what in essence does 'self.sid = id' do? Isn't it usually 'self.something = something'? (Do note, I'm a Python beginner) EDIT: Tried that. Code still works, but the error message hasn't changed. Does it have anything to do with the existence of the `allocated_project` being `None`?

Comment: The (extremely powerful, yet somewhat mystical) semantics of `__getattr__` still have me befuddled. Good luck. +1 for a well presented question.

Comment: `self.id = id` is proper idiom, since I guessed that the `Column('id'` was hiding `self.id` I suggested a quick-and-dirty check. The only meaning of `sid` was that it wasn't `id`, it could have been `fred` just as well to test my guess.

Comment: As I'm just at beginner+epsilon level, I'd start reading `sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py` at this point, but I'm not responsible if your head explodes o_O